# Google Apps Script: How to remove specific characters from a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, replace

In Google Apps Script how do you run through a 2D array and remove specific characters? For example, if I wanted to remove the ";" symbol I could use **.replace(";","")**, but how do you run this through every row and every column of the array? I'm thinking this could be setup starting with the following formula, but just need to solve for the function in the middle:

```
var cleanedarray = originalarray.map(function (row){         });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can use an internal mapping function inside your original map to replace all ocurrances in the 2D array returned by `.getValues()`.*

#### Code:

```js
function replaceAll() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(
    sheet.getDataRange().getValues().map(
      x => x.map(
        y => y.replace(';', ',')
      )
  ));
}
```

#### References:

- [Array.prototype.map() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeCharacter(ch) {
  var ch=ch||';';
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  const re=new RegExp(ch,'g');//build the regex with RegExp
  var v=rg.getValues();
  v.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      v[i][j]=c.toString().replace(re,'');
    });
  });
  rg.setValues(v);  
}
```